# Difference between '<<' and 'put()' for output filestreams

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

I am trying to understand the difference between the '<<' operator and the 'put()' function for writing characters to an output file.

My code:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream out ("output.txt");

    int x = 1;

    // This produces the incorrect result ...
    out.put(x);
    
    // ... while this produces the correct result
    out << x;


    // These two produce the same (correct) result
    out.put('a');
    out << 'a';
    
    out.close;
}
```

I get that `out.put(x)` converts the integer 1 into a character according ASCII code, but I don't understand why this doesn't happen when I use `out << x`.

However, `out.put('a')` **does** produce the same as `out << 'a'`.

Why is this?

Comment: [`ostream::put()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) outputs a *character*. There are no overloads for `int` or any other type.

Comment: The `<<` as a streaming operator taps into the conversion, type aware output, locale & culture, and converter machinery that's part of C++ I/O subsystem.  Some people dislike the facility because it bring along a fairly large I/O subsystem for small programs.  The `put` method bypasses most of that machinery to just output a given character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = 1;

// This produces the incorrect result ...
out.put(x);
```

No, it converts the `int` to a `char` and outputs one `char`, with the value `1`.

```
// ... while this produces the correct result
out << x;
```

That does formatted output and outputs the the representation of the value `x` holds. Most probably it'll show the character `1` which is different from the character with value `1`.

```
// These two produce the same (correct) result
out.put('a');
out << 'a';
```

Yes, there's no conversion there. Had you done

```
int x = 'A';
out.put(x);
out << x;
```

You'd probably see `A65` where `A` comes from the `put(x)` and `65` from the formatted output since `65` is often the value of `'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `out << 1`, you call: `operator<<(int val)` and not: `operator<<(char val)`, then he can cast `int` to `std::string`.

Comment: The stream inserter doesn't **cast** from `int` to `std::string`. It **converts** the `int` value to text. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.